# Find results based on other results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table called *Info.Case*, which lists all the cases we have, *Info.Person* which lists all the people in the database, and a table called *Links.Case_Person*, which lists how each person relates to each case.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Find all the cases John Smith (**Person_ID = 123**) is listed as Primary (**Role_ID = 5**) or Secondary (**Role_ID = 11**).

So far this is not an issue:

```
SELECT * FROM Info.Case IC
INNER JOIN Links.Case_Person LC
ON IC.Case_ID = LC.Case_ID
INNER JOIN Info.Person IP
ON LC.Person_ID = IP.Person_ID
WHERE LC.Person_ID = 123 AND LC.Role_ID IN (5, 11)
```

This generates 100 Cases.

Now I want know know if there was also an assistant (**Role_ID = 22**) on any of these specific 100 John Smith cases. So I want to search just the 100 cases for any Role_ID = 22.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data and desired results, can't be too confident, but it sounds like you just need to add a check for the existence of assistants on the same cases:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Links.Case_Person AS cp
  WHERE cp.Case_ID = LC.Case_ID AND cp.Role_ID = 22);
```

Based on the comments below it seems your description doesn't quite match your stated requirements above. Perhaps, then:

```
SELECT *, 
  HasAssistant = CASE WHEN LC2.Case_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Info.Case IC
INNER JOIN Links.Case_Person LC
ON IC.Case_ID = LC.Case_ID
INNER JOIN Info.Person IP
ON LC.Person_ID = IP.Person_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Links.Case_Person AS LC2
ON LC.Case_ID = LC2.Case_ID
AND LC2.Role_ID = 22
WHERE LC.Person_ID = 123 AND LC.Role_ID IN (5, 11);
```

(Note that if it is possible for a case to have more than one assistant, that case will produce multiple rows here. There are ways around that, but your specific requirements are still not clear to me.)

Comment: Thank you, Aaron. I thought using the AND would limit me to only the cases where Role_ID = 22. I need all 100 results from the original code and of those 100, IF there was a Role_ID = 22, then to also include that.  Thanks again for the help, I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @MarkThompson Then please update your question with sample data and desired results. Word problems are, as you can see, confusing.

Comment: I apologize if my wording was misleading. Its funny how things make sense in your head but when you verbalize it, it makes no sense. It also sucks when I waste your time solving my problem when you don't even know the exact problem.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Mark Please, no more word problems. Just show sample data and desired results (e.g. at least one John row you want to include, and at least one John row you want to exclude).

Comment: Understood Aaron. Since I do not know how to copy data over to show you, I'll stop posting. I'm having enough issues trying to hit enter to start typing on a new line. Have a good day and thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: @Mark Post create table / insert statements here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3 And then run my suggestions against that sample data and explain why neither query actually meets your requirement. I'm willing to help you, just not interested in more word problems, that's all.